# Match .file with POSIX extended regular expression

Tags: linux, postfix

I am trying to match any file with a dot in the front using POSIX extended regular expression. I know in regex this is `^\..*`.

This is what I'm using it in:

```
#!/bin/sh
MONITORDIR1="/hdd_1/path/to/dir"
MONITORDIR2="/hdd_1/path/to/dir"
#MONITORDIR3="/hdd_1/path/to/dir"
#MONITORDIR4="/hdd_1/path/to/dir"

monitor() {
inotifywait -m -r -e create --format "%f" "$1" | while read NEWFILE
do
echo "This is an automated email." | mail -s "${NEWFILE} has been added to Daemon!" "user@domain.com"
done
}
monitor "$MONITORDIR1" &
monitor "$MONITORDIR2" &
#monitor "$MONITORDIR3" &
#monitor "$MONITORDIR4" &
```

Comment: What problem are you having?  This should work in posix too.

Comment: @Paul I'm using `--exclude` within `inotifywait`. I am just attempting to exclude any file that starts with a dot.

Comment: @Paul I also added the context to which I am using this for in the question.

Comment: Hmm.  If I do `inotifywait --exclude='\..*' <folder>` it triggers on a normal filename but not on a dot-prefix filename.

Comment: @Paul So I tried it with and without the `^`. It doesn't like the `^`. The problem with the syntax that you tried, is that a file like test.dl excluded also. I only need `.*` excluded. Which you already know :P

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
MONITORDIR1="/hdd_1/path/to/dir"
MONITORDIR2="/hdd_1/path/to/dir"
#MONITORDIR3="/hdd_1/path/to/dir"
#MONITORDIR4="/hdd_1/path/to/dir"

monitor() {
inotifywait -m -r -e create --exclude '/\..+' --format "%f" "$1" | while read NEWFILE
do
        echo "This is an automated email." | mail -s "${NEWFILE} has been added to Daemon!" "user@domain.com"
done
}
monitor "$MONITORDIR1" &
monitor "$MONITORDIR2" &
#monitor "$MONITORDIR3" &
#monitor "$MONITORDIR4" &
```